# Angularjs Firebase Form submit

Tags: angularjs, forms, firebase

I'm new to Angular and just working on a first *learning-by-doing-app* and things are ok, but now I wanted to connect it to Firebase to give it a try but I can't figure out how to get it working.

What I want to get: 
I have a form with several inputs. Clicking on a submit button should add those input content to my data and it should be displayed once it's synct. I worked through the Angular CodeSchool course and read through the Firebase docs, but somehow I'm stuck and hope you can help me!

Important Parts of my HTML:

```
<div class="subsite" ng-show="tab === 3">
    <h1>New</h1>
<div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="ListController as listing">           
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
            <th  class="col-md-2">Date</th>
            <th  class="col-md-7">Type</th>
            <th  class="col-md-1">Repeats</th>
            <th  class="col-md-2">Time</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-controller="ListController as listing">
    <tr ng-repeat="wo in listing.sessions">
            <td>{{wo.date}} </td>
            <td>{{wo.name}}</td>
            <td>{{wo.repeat}}</td>
            <td>{{wo.time}} minutes</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    </div>

<h3>Add new:</h3>
<form class="form-inline" name="WorkoutForm" ng-controller="EntryController">
    <blockquote>
        <h4>Last Workout:</h4>
        <strong>{{wo.name}}</strong><br>
        <small>am: {{wo.date}}</small><br>
        {{wo.repeat}} repeats in {{wo.time}} minutes.
</blockquote>

<input class="form-control" ng-model="wo.date" type="name" placeholder="date" />
<input class="form-control" ng-model="wo.name" type="name" placeholder="name"  />
<input class="form-control" ng-model="wo.repeat" type="repeat" placeholder="repeat"  />
<input class="form-control" ng-model="wo.time" type="name" placeholder="time"  />
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">Add</button>
</form>
</div>
```

And my app.js looks like this:

```
(function(){   
var app = angular.module('wobuddy', [ "firebase"]);

// Lists all Entries
app.controller('ListController', function($firebaseObject){
    var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
    this.sessions = syncObject;       
});

// Adds new Entry
app.controller('EntryController', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {

// What the Firebase site told me: 
 var ref = new Firebase("http://myurl.firebaseio.com/data");
  var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
  syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");

    // How I solved it with local data 
    $scope.submit = function() {
    wos.push($scope.wo);
    $scope.wo = {};  // Clear the form fields
  };
 });    
})();
```

Again: If I click on submit the data should be synced to my firebase and displayed in the table above. You helped me once today, I'm pretty thankful for another help.

Comment: would it help to just replace the "wos" with data? Still can't get it working...

Comment: What exactly is `wos` here? I don't see it defined in your example and that seems like a critical component. Also, where is this data supposed to be synced to Firebase? I don't see anything putting it into `$scope.data`, which is what you've bound to Firebase. Additionally, are we incorrectly using `$firebaseObject()` to contain a collection, [contrary to the recommendations of the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html)?